# Can weird words target the same target multiple times in the same round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bard, archetype

I need some help figuring out an ability from a bard archtype called [sound striker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/sound-striker).

Weird Words (Su)

> At 6th level, a sound striker can start a performance as a standard action, lashing out with 1 potent sound per bard level (maximum 10), each sound affecting one target within 30 feet. These are ranged touch attacks. Each weird word deals 1d8 points of damage plus the bard’s Charisma bonus (Fortitude half ), and the bard chooses whether it deals bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing damage for each word.

The bard in question is level 8 which means they have about 24 uses of bardic performance a day. The way the ability is worded makes it clear that each of the weird words could strike a different target. What is unclear is weather you can target the same creature multiple times in the same round. It seems like  high damage as it would be 8d8+8*cha for 20 rounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use the update from the [*Ultimate Magic* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fz#v5748eaic9t4f)

It includes the following exchange:

> **Question:** The sound striker’s weird words ability is confusing. Does it work more than once on the same target? And does it require 30 rolls to adjudicate?
>   **Answer:** Change the text of weird words to the following “At 6th level the bard can start a performance that is always a standard action to speak up to one word per 4 bard levels laden with sonic energy. Each word deals 4d6 points of sonic damage as a ranged touch attack with a range of 30 feet. The bard adds his charisma modifier on damage rolls with weird words. Multiple words that strike the same target stack into a single powerful attack, applying energy resistance and bonuses on damage rolls only once. The bard can target all words at the same or different targets, but he unleashes all words simultaneously. Each word costs 1 round of bardic performance.” This change will be reflected in future errata.

Such a change isn't reflected yet in the *d20PFSRD* of the [sound striker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo---bard-archetypes/sound-striker).

Comment: Thank you for showing me the FAQ, thats exactly the answer I needed, and also quite the change to the ability.

Comment: @Fering Questions mirroring yours about the original language of weird words (O, the irony!) on the Paizo messageboards yielded two heated 3-page threads and, like, 100 FAQ requests before the ability was entirely rewritten. While the original is more interesting, the rewritten version is more playable.